# laravel making categories for a post (normalizing table)

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel normalizing relationship in DB.

So I've jobs table that contains job. And categories table that contains category.

job can have multiple categories.

Is there a laravely way of normalizing the relationship?

```
Schema::create('jobs', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('excerpt')->nullable();
            $table->text('content');
            $table->integer('delivery');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->unique(array('user_id', 'slug'));
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('categories', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
      // These columns are needed for Baum's Nested Set implementation to work.
      // Column names may be changed, but they *must* all exist and be modified
      // in the model.
      // Take a look at the model scaffold comments for details.
      // We add indexes on parent_id, lft, rgt columns by default.
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable()->index();
      $table->integer('lft')->nullable()->index();
      $table->integer('rgt')->nullable()->index();
      $table->integer('depth')->nullable();

      // Add additional columns here (f.ex: name, slug, path, etc.)
      $table->string('name')->unique();
      $table->string('slug')->unique();
      $table->string('description')->nullable();
    });
```

My first instinct is to create an intermediary table that holds relationship:

```
Schema::create('jobs_categories', function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->unique(array('job_id', 'category_id'));
        });
```

But I'm not sure how to proceede, what would I do if I want to get categories along with all $jobs?

What do I do if I want to get $job category?

Is hasOne, hasMany a better suited for this?

Comment: It depends.  A job can have multiple categories.  Can the same category belong to multiple jobs?

Comment: @user3158900 yeah, why not? post has many categories, and categories have many posts.

Comment: lukasgeiter has a good answer so I'm not going to bother creating another, but the only thin I would add is Laravel expects the pivot table to be singular and in alphabetical order.  Just change `jobs_categories` to `category_job`

Comment: @user3158900 Have you read my answer? (First sentence in the Pivot table section) ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're describing is a many-to-many relationship. And yes, a pivot table like `jobs_categories` is needed. Here's how you do it following Laravels naming convention and making use of relationships:

### Pivot table

`jobs_categories` is fine but Laravel likes `category_job` (singular and alphabetical order) (This way you don't have to specify the table name in your relation)

```
Schema::create('category_job', function($table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->unique(array('job_id', 'category_id'));

    // foreign key constraints are optional (but pretty useful, especially with cascade delete
    $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

### Relationships

#### Job model

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
}
```

#### Category model

```
public function jobs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Job');
}
```

### Usage

Jobs with categories eager loaded

```
$jobs = Job::with('categories')->get();
```

Access categories of a job

```
$job = Job::find(1);
$categories = $job->categories;
```

[Visit the Laravel docs for more information on Eloquent relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)